# weird gateway in vmnet

Tags: linux, vmware, gateway

I have vmnet8 interface with ip

```
 192.168.146.1/24
```

and virtual machines are getting ip
in this network, and of course are able to ping this interface and in normal scenario it
should be the gateway here, but is not.

When i checked the gateway in virtual machine, it is showing

```
192.168.146.2/24
```

and it is also pingable through VM, but when i try to ping from my localhost, that VM with ip

```
192.168.146.129/24
```

gets pinged and not this weird `192.168.146.2/24`,

when ran ARP on VM, it showed the MAC address for this ip as well as for vmnet8 interface.

What am I missing here? though connectivity works fine but just curious

Comment: Vmnet8 uses 192.168.146.2 as gateway and DNS server. It's an implementation decision by VMware and no point in asking why.

Comment: There is nothing weird here. I am posting from a VM using NAT. IP and DNS/Gateway works perfectly. What are you trying to do / and be concerned about?

Comment: Like, when we run docker containers they get ips in the range 172.16.0.0/16 range, and their gateway is 172.16.0.1/16 which is of docker0 interface,
Similarly, why vms are not having gateway ip of vmnet8 interface?

i expected this:   `192.168.146.129 --->  192.168.146.1  --->  outside`


but seeing this:   `192.168.146.129 --->  192.168.146.2  ---> 192.168.146.1 ---> outside`

Comment: 192.168.146.129 --->  192.168.146.2  ---> 192.168.146.1 ---> outside   ....  No. VMware NAT networking provides its own complete DHCP server. So the Gateway   ... .2  is correct.  My Gateway is ... .2 as well.    Please see:     https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-47E9FA43-AED1-42CD-8AE9-BAB8B7CF652E.html     My DNS server is the internal NAT  .254

Comment: thanks a lot @John and also for docs link!